# image zooming using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, zooming

I need some code to zoom an image when i mouse over that image, i want to zoom that image.

Consider i have 10 images in y page, when i put mouse over in first image that image should zoom and when i mov to second second image should zoom like that...

how can i do this, need some javascript or jquery something like that.But not sure.how can i do this...

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://blogs.oreilly.com/wateringhole/) does something pretty similar.  You have to click on the image to zoom it, which might be preferable to it just popping up when you mouse over it.  The function that handles the OnClick event is `hs.expand`

Answer (score 2):

`img:hover  { zoom: 1.5 }`